# remove quantity box for specific product

Tags: magento

Good morning I installed Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 and I need to delete the box quantity only on some products. I was thinking, for example, when max quantity is set to 1, instead for other products leave the box. Thank you, do you have any suggestions?

Nicola

I tried to modify the file addtochar.phtml but without success. I attach the code
?>getProduct(); ?> **('Add to Cart'); ?> isSaleable()): ?> isGrouped()): ?> __('Qty:') ?> getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="quoteEscape($this->**('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" /> " id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"> getChildHtml('', true, true) ?> showButtonDesign(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you.

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <?php $hiddenFlag = in_array($_product->getId(), array(10,20,30,40)) ? true : false; ?>
    <?php if (!$hiddenFlag): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
    <?php endif;?>
    <input type="<?php echo $hiddenFlag ? 'hidden' : 'text' ?>" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
```

Please pay attention to this line: `<?php $hiddenFlag = in_array($_product->getId(), array(10,20,30,40)) ? true : false; ?> it will check if product eligible for a qty visibility.`

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know if you can remove the box quantity to certain products defined by ID.
For example, indicate ID 10,11,12,13,20,30 etc. and remove the box quantity from the products with these IDs.